# How to include dependencies from another directory with ocamlbuild?

Tags: module, directory, ocaml, ocamlbuild

I'm writing an OCaml program that I want to be organized, so I have this directory structure:

```
src
 |- folder1
 |   |- a.ml
 |- folder2
 |   |- b.ml
```

Note: `b.ml` uses `open A` to reference `a.ml`.

I want to test my code to see if it works. I have successfully run `ocamlbuild a.native` while in the `folder1` directory. When I tried doing the same thing in the `folder2` directory with `b.ml`, I got an error saying that the module `A` was unbound.

I have tried doing it from the `src` directory with the same result.

Can anyone please point out to me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer:

Add a `_tags` file to the `src` folder, so the structure looks like this:

```
src
 |- folder1
 |   |- a.ml
 |- folder2
 |   |- b.ml
 |- _tags
```

Then modify the `_tags` file to include the following:

```
<folder1> or <folder2>: include
```

Then run `ocamlbuild folder2/b.native` from the `src` directory.